# How to use tapply to match specific condition

Tags: r, tapply

I have accident dataset that contains number of accidents being reported. I am trying to use `tapply` function, that will display me the total number of accidents being reported on "Thursday".  However, instead of returning number of accidents being reported for particular day. It is displaying total number of rows I have in my dataset.I am using below `tapply` function.:

```
tapply(myfinal$VEHICLE_COUNT,myfinal$DAY_OF_WEEK=='THURSDAY',length)
```

My sample dataset is as follows:

```
> dput(tail(myfinal,5))
structure(list(CASE_NUMBER = c("1251045636", "1251045630", "1251045591", 
"1251045574", "1250010434"), BARRACK = c("Frederick", "Frederick", 
"Frederick", "Frederick", "Jessup"), ACC_DATE = c("2012-12-31T00:00:00", 
"2012-12-31T00:00:00", "2012-12-31T00:00:00", "2012-12-31T00:00:00", 
"2012-12-31T00:00:00"), ACC_TIME = c("18:12", "18:12", "12:12", 
"9:12", "11:12"), ACC_TIME_CODE = c("5", "5", "4", "3", "3"), 
    DAY_OF_WEEK = c("MONDAY   ", "MONDAY   ", "MONDAY   ", "MONDAY   ", 
    "MONDAY   "), ROAD = c("IS 00070 EISENHOWER MEMOR HWY", "MD 00077 ROCKY RIDGE RD", 
    "MD 00085 BUCKEYSTOWN PIKE", "MD 00017 MYERSVILLE RD", "IS 00070 No Name"
    ), INTERSECT_ROAD = c("CO 00248 MONUMENT RD", "MD 00076 MOTTERS STATION RD", 
    "CO 00308 MANOR WOODS RD", "CO 00941 DAWN CT", "US 00029 Columbia Pike"
    ), DIST_FROM_INTERSECT = c("300", "0", "400", "500", "0.25"
    ), DIST_DIRECTION = c("E", "U", "S", "S", "E"), CITY_NAME = c("Not Applicable", 
    "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable", NA), 
    COUNTY_CODE = c("10", "10", "10", "10", "13"), COUNTY_NAME = c("Frederick", 
    "Frederick", "Frederick", "Frederick", "Howard"), VEHICLE_COUNT = c(1, 
    2, 2, 1, 2), PROP_DEST = c("NO", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO"
    ), INJURY = c("YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES"), COLLISION_WITH_1 = c("FIXED OBJ", 
    "VEH", "VEH", "NON-COLLISION", "VEH"), COLLISION_WITH_2 = c("OTHER-COLLISION", 
    "OTHER-COLLISION", "OTHER-COLLISION", "OTHER-COLLISION", 
    "OTHER-COLLISION")), .Names = c("CASE_NUMBER", "BARRACK", 
"ACC_DATE", "ACC_TIME", "ACC_TIME_CODE", "DAY_OF_WEEK", "ROAD", 
"INTERSECT_ROAD", "DIST_FROM_INTERSECT", "DIST_DIRECTION", "CITY_NAME", 
"COUNTY_CODE", "COUNTY_NAME", "VEHICLE_COUNT", "PROP_DEST", "INJURY", 
"COLLISION_WITH_1", "COLLISION_WITH_2"), row.names = 18634:18638, class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If can only use tapply for whatever reason, then, building off of Maurits' answer, you should be able to do this:

```
tapply(myfinal$VEHICLE_COUNT,trimws(myfinal$DAY_OF_WEEK)=='THURSDAY',length)
```

Or similar. It seems that the strings in your DAY_OF_WEEK variable have a lot of whitespaces at the end. You either need to remove them (via `trimws`) or modify your comparison string to include these spaces (e.g., `myfinal$DAY_OF_WEEK=="THURSDAY    "`). With the comparison operator, R will match two string only if they match exactly character by character, so any additional whitespaces in either string will count against you.

Comment: Is there a way to just display only TRUE condition. At present, it is displaying me both TRUE and FALSE condition ?

Comment: The most direct way would be `tapply(myfinal$VEHICLE_COUNT,trimws(myfinal$DAY_OF_WEEK)=='THURSDAY',length)["TRUE"]`. In the future, there are better ways to write this type of code that just looks cleaner and is likely more maintainable. For example, `sum(trimws(myfinal$DAY_OF_WEEK)=='THURSDAY')`.

Comment: would it be possible for you to answer another question related to same topic ?

Comment: Sure, although if the question is separate enough from this one, you technically should make a new post.

Comment: @Daniel..ok. Thanks! it's on tapply only. I am trying to find number of accidents that had injuries.How would that work out using tapply ONLY ? there is some NA's in INJURY  and VEHICLE_COUNT column

Comment: In this small space without any decent explanation, you could try `tapply(myfinal$VEHICLE_COUNT,trimws(myfinal$DAY_OF_WEEK)=='THURSDAY' & myfinal$INJURY == 'YES' & !is.na(myfinal$DAY_OF_WEEK) & !is.na(myfinal$INJURY),length)["TRUE"]`. You can modify this to add more conditionals, but this is starting to get quite unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no point in using `tapply` here!

### Method 1

Use `dplyr`:

```
require(tidyverse);
df %>% filter(trimws(DAY_OF_WEEK) == "MONDAY") %>% summarise(count = n());
#  count
#1     5
```

---

### Method 2

In base R, use `subset` and `table`

```
table(subset(df, trimws(DAY_OF_WEEK) == "MONDAY")$DAY_OF_WEEK);
#MONDAY
#    5
```

I've used "MONDAY" here because you've got no entries with `DAY_OF_WEEK = "THURSDAY"`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- structure(list(CASE_NUMBER = c("1251045636", "1251045630", "1251045591",
"1251045574", "1250010434"), BARRACK = c("Frederick", "Frederick",
"Frederick", "Frederick", "Jessup"), ACC_DATE = c("2012-12-31T00:00:00",
"2012-12-31T00:00:00", "2012-12-31T00:00:00", "2012-12-31T00:00:00",
"2012-12-31T00:00:00"), ACC_TIME = c("18:12", "18:12", "12:12",
"9:12", "11:12"), ACC_TIME_CODE = c("5", "5", "4", "3", "3"),
    DAY_OF_WEEK = c("MONDAY   ", "MONDAY   ", "MONDAY   ", "MONDAY   ",
    "MONDAY   "), ROAD = c("IS 00070 EISENHOWER MEMOR HWY", "MD 00077 ROCKY RIDGE RD",
    "MD 00085 BUCKEYSTOWN PIKE", "MD 00017 MYERSVILLE RD", "IS 00070 No Name"
    ), INTERSECT_ROAD = c("CO 00248 MONUMENT RD", "MD 00076 MOTTERS STATION RD",
    "CO 00308 MANOR WOODS RD", "CO 00941 DAWN CT", "US 00029 Columbia Pike"
    ), DIST_FROM_INTERSECT = c("300", "0", "400", "500", "0.25"
    ), DIST_DIRECTION = c("E", "U", "S", "S", "E"), CITY_NAME = c("Not Applicable",
    "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable", NA),
    COUNTY_CODE = c("10", "10", "10", "10", "13"), COUNTY_NAME = c("Frederick",
    "Frederick", "Frederick", "Frederick", "Howard"), VEHICLE_COUNT = c(1,
    2, 2, 1, 2), PROP_DEST = c("NO", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO"
    ), INJURY = c("YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES"), COLLISION_WITH_1 = c("FIXED OBJ",
    "VEH", "VEH", "NON-COLLISION", "VEH"), COLLISION_WITH_2 = c("OTHER-COLLISION",
    "OTHER-COLLISION", "OTHER-COLLISION", "OTHER-COLLISION",
    "OTHER-COLLISION")), .Names = c("CASE_NUMBER", "BARRACK",
"ACC_DATE", "ACC_TIME", "ACC_TIME_CODE", "DAY_OF_WEEK", "ROAD",
"INTERSECT_ROAD", "DIST_FROM_INTERSECT", "DIST_DIRECTION", "CITY_NAME",
"COUNTY_CODE", "COUNTY_NAME", "VEHICLE_COUNT", "PROP_DEST", "INJURY",
"COLLISION_WITH_1", "COLLISION_WITH_2"), row.names = 18634:18638, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I would like to use Only tapply function

Comment: @YesBoss There is really no point in using `tapply` here. I've updated my solution to show you two methods.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting alternate method. Thanks again for help!

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution is to subset `DAY_OF_WEEK` by "THURSDAY" and then return number of rows:

```
nrow(df[df$DAY_OF_WEEK == "THURSDAY",])
```

Comment: It is returning me value of 0. I was thinking of same

Comment: That's because his dataset introduces white spaces.  In Daniels answer, he uses the command `trimws` to drop white spaces. I just ignored them because this is the (generic) solution to the problem.